# How to mount ftp mounted .iso file to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ftp, repository, iso

In my windows, I have created a folder. I have mounted that folder using curlftps. It was successful. there's a .iso file (centos.iso) in that folder. Then I tried to mount that iso image to my linux again in a mount point. But it was unsuccessful.

```
root@UbuntuServer:/mnt/test# mount -o loop CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso /mnt/test2/
mount: /mnt/test/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso: failed to setup loop device: Operation not supported  


root@UbuntuServer:~# curlftpfs ftp://randeer:randeer@192.168.0.2 /mnt/test/
root@UbuntuServer:~# ls -l
total 0
root@UbuntuServer:~# cd /mnt/test/
root@UbuntuServer:/mnt/test# ls
CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso  new public             rootnewprivate.ppk
fromcentos.txt                       randeernewprivate.ppk  rootpub
root@UbuntuServer:/mnt/test# mount CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso /mnt/test                                                                                        2/ -t iso9600 -o loop
mount: /mnt/test/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso: failed to setup loop device
```

[image: my screenshot]

Comment: Hello, Lets get a little more information. What version of mount are you using? `mount --version`. What is currently mounted, do you need a remount? `mount`. Try the mount command again with the verbose switch. `sudo mount --verbose -o loop /path/centOS.iso /mnt/test2`. Post the outputs in text...

Comment: @jc__ - I ran the command as u specify early. but it didn't give me any specific details. root@UbuntuServer:~# curlftpfs ftp://test:test@192.168.0.2 /mnt/test/
root@UbuntuServer:~# ls /mnt/test/
CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso  test.txt
root@UbuntuServer:~# mount --verbose -o loop /mnt/test/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso /mnt/test2
mount: /mnt/test/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1804.iso: failed to setup loop device: Operation not supported

Comment: mount version is : mount from util-linux 2.27.1 (libmount 2.27.0: selinux, assert, debug)

Answer (score 1):

curlftps is userspace, mount loopback is kernelspace. Kernel can't see the userspace mounted file. Use [fuseiso](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso/) for mounting which is a userspace based solution.

Comment: Thanks mate, it works. 1)apt install fuseiso . 2) modprobe fuse 3)mkdir /mnt/iso 4)fuseiso -p /mnt/test/CentOS-7.iso /mnt/iso/